# After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10, other devices are not able to keep connection with WiFi

Tags: wireless, 13.04, android

After I upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10 my other devices are not able to keep connected to WiFi.

When I connect Ubuntu 13.04 with my WiFi connection, my other devices Galaxy S3 and Nexus 7 tablet can't keep connection to WiFi, it keeps getting disconnected.

Comment: This is definitely a BUG I have the same on 7 separate machines, ironically this bug occurs in Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu..in my case all lenovo thinkpads models w510, w530 and t410..with wireless working fine when running non 13x. Im RIGHT next to router that was working fine before three days ago when I began running different versions of Ubuntu 13. Google gives a fair amount of data of others having the same proble,, which occurs with fresh install and after updates as of 2013.05.03...so far I have not seen a bug filed or a fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

The proprietary Broadcom driver was the issue for me.

Go to:  System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers tab -> Check "do not use the device" under the Broadcom section to disable the proprietary drivers and switch to Ubuntu's open driver.  Press Apply then restart the computer.  All should be good.

Comment: I tried doing same, but its turning back to same selection after processing, i dont know whats wrong with this new upgrade.